# An imposed project. How to handle this situation?

Tags: research-process, supervision

So we are working on a sponsored project. My adviser has assigned two fellows to the project, taking the funding of two people from the organisation. However internally, only I will work on the project and the adviser will let the other fellow work on his proposed project. I am disturbed by this fact as I will have all the project load and the other fellow gets to work on his own proposals. This seems unfair and biased. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The situation is complex and probably can't be resolved without more information. You, of course, have some of that information. All I can propose is a framework and some options.

An extreme option is that you refuse. The likely outcome is that you need a different advisor and you need to come up with a different project or depend on the new advisor to give you one. You may also need different funding. The new project may be more to your liking or not. Beware of the *not*.

Consider that the "load" may not be so different between the two people. The other project may be less defined and more risky, also, but I can't say, of course.

Judge for yourself how successful completion of the project will work to meet your goals (or not). If it is a good project, even if hard, but has a clear set of goals and a framework then it may actually be easier to complete than one less well defined.

You don't say whether you proposed your own project to your advisor or not. And if so, what s/he thought of it and its likelihood of success. Perhaps, and I can't say, you are being given a gift, not a burden. But you need to judge that.

The other extreme from rejection is acceptance of the project, but in this case you will need to find something in it to make you enthused, so that it isn't painful to work on it. Maybe there is something interesting there for you and maybe not.

Whether there is a middle position between the extremes or not depends on what you and your advisor can come up with, but it will require a discussion to achieve anything in the middle. To have a fruitful discussion you need a positive attitude, of course.

So, it is your call, but consider all of the options and think about the likelihood of the consequences of each choice.